# How can I suppress the pop up blocker on mobile phones when my application I and going from a Linux server running Wordpress to a Windows server?

Tags: linux, iphone, wordpress, windows-server

My website and the payment form are in Wordpress on a Linux server. The calculation/product delivery (a digital report) are on a Windows server. After the payment is made, the user clicks a button to go to the report section and then get stopped because of pop-up blockers. If you retry, you can make it work. The average user does not retry. Is there a technique I can use to get around the pop-up blocker? Maybe send the command twice behind a black screen? I've looked at moving everything to Windows but that will be hundreds of problems based on the performance of my current technical team. Any ideas for a quick fix?

Currently, my tech team has no solution. I'm stuck in Windows for my report generation and delivery system.

Comment: Why are you using a pop-up when you know people hate them so much that they install pop-up blockers? Why not embed the content in your page?

Comment: When I go from one server to another, it is interpreted by the security systems on mobile phones as a pop-up. I don't want it to be seen as a pop-up. I want to find a way to switch servers and not have it seen as a pop-up. I would like to retain the current server configuration and somehow get by the pop-up that prevents the transfer to the other server that delivers the report.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.